# How to get a value of key from csv file sing bash script?

Tags: bash, csv

Suppose I have csv file as follows:

```
SNo,Name,Country,uniqueness
1,abs,US,randomStringHavingUniqueString
2,xyz,UK,randomString
```

Now I want to get value of `uniqueness` only if it has `UniqueString` as part of it's value for uniqueness column.

The value I should get from this csv is `randomStringHavingUniqueString` because this string has substring `UniqueString`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The bash script I was looking for was like this

returns first match

`grep 'UniqueString' path/to/file.csv|cut -f2 -d,|head -1`

to get the array of matches

```
targets=($(grep 'UniqueString' path/to/file.csv|cut -f2 -d,))
for match in ${targets[@]}
do
    echo match
done
```

Answer (score 1):

This command will get the desired result:

```
awk -F',' '$4 ~ "UniqueString" && NR > 1 {print}' file.csv
```

Output:

```
1,abs,US,randomStringHavingUniqueString
```

I am removing the header, you need to modify the command if you need the header.

Comment: Instead of `tail -n +2` you can use `sed 1d`.

Comment: `NR > 1` for `awk`

Answer (score 1):

Using [Miller](https://github.com/johnkerl/miller), and running

```
mlr --c2n filter -S '$uniqueness=~"UniqueString"' then cut -f uniqueness input.csv
```

you have `randomStringHavingUniqueString`.

Some details:

- `filter -S '$uniqueness=~"UniqueString"'` to apply string filter to `uniqueness` field;
- `cut -f uniqueness` to have in output only `uniqueness` field.